# java/PHP bridge, returning List into PHP

Tags: java, php, list, php-java-bridge

Currently i am new into PHP, and I'm using Java/PHP bridge in my project. 
I need to call java method from PHP script

```
 public List<Notification> getNotifications()
  {
    return getNotifications(50);
  }
```

which returns List type, and as I know PHP doesn't support this data type. So the question is, which is the best way to save result in PHP variable (or another structure).

```
$notifications =   $some_instantiated_object->getNotifications();
```

this one causes exception

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389689/working-with-php-java-bridge